# Sound not working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after update

Tags: dual-boot, sound, updates, pulseaudio, 20.04

I recently updated from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS and there is no sound. I dual boot my PC with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Windows 10 and sound is working fine in Windows.

I have tried every guide and instruction I can find online from StackExchange to blogs but the problem still exists. I've even tried to reinstall `pulseaudio` and `alsa` but it is still not working.